# Can't find a way to approximate $R_n(x)$ of this series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785454/proving-uniform-convergence-of-this-series?rq=1), the solver depended on a way I didn't use to solve in.

I thought of finding a bound for $|R_n(x)|$ that's going to $0$ in order to prove the uniform convergence. But I always find a problem dealing with $(-1)^n$. I think of using the fact that in alternating convergent series, the first term dominates.

$|R_n(x)| = |\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^2 + k}{k^2}| \leq |(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^2+n+1}{(n+1)^2}|= \frac{x^2+n+1}{(n+1)^2}$ but then,

$|R_n(n)| \leq  \frac{n^2+n+1}{(n+1)^2} \longrightarrow 1$ not $0$. So for sure I'm doing mistakes in estimating, since the answer is "uniformly convergent".

Guys, I'm just a beginner, you can call me a self learner. Please help me as I feel I won't be good at such problems :(

Answer (score 0):

We observe that $S:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{x^2 + k}{k^2}$ is an alternating series.

We put
$\displaystyle\ S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k\frac{x^2 + k}{k^2},$ and
$b_n=\frac{x^2 + n}{n^2}.$

We have:
(i) $\left\{b_n\right\}$ is a decreasing sequence.
$S_{2n+1}<S_{2n}, S_{2n+2}=S_{2n}+b_{2n+1}-b_{2n}<S_{2n}$, and
$S_{2n+3}=S_{2n+1}+b_{2n+2}-b_{2n+3}>S_{2n+1}.$

Therefore, $S_{2n+1}<S<S_{2n}.$

$|R_{2n+1}(x)|<S_{2n}(x)-S_{2n+1}(x)=\frac{x^2 + (2n+1)}{(2n+1)^2}.$

Similarly, we obtain an evaluation for $|R_{2n+1}(x)|.$